# how to refresh JQuery UI tab after updating the other tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two jquery UI tabs. On the first tab I have a form where I have jquery ajax submit. The 2nd tab shows data belonging to the first tab. I need to reload the 2nd tab after any ajax call. The view mark up looks like below

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Member Sites </a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Services and Packages</a></li>
 </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
       @Html.Partial("_MemberSites")
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      @Html.Action("somemethod", new { @id = @Model.MemberNumber })
   </div>
</div>
```

and the ajax call is

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/somecontroller/somemethod",
        content: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        data: {passing  some data},
        success: function (data) {
        window.location.reload(true);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

`window.location.reload(true)` is working but it reloads whole page and it does not look nice. So is there a way we can refresh the 2nd tab without using reload method? thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning the data belongs to the second tab you can try this.

```
success: function(data) {
 $('#tabs-2').html(data);
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Still does not work. I need to reload or call this action method after success `@Html.Action("somemethod", new { @id = @Model.MemberNumber })`

Comment: according to your requirement its bettor load it as normal ajax load. try the edited answer

Comment: ermm that will be a bigger change in the source. There must be another way around this issue

Comment: may i know what will be the return value of this ajax post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73419/discussion-between-iceburg-and-learner).